# How do I select everything from a specific column, from a specific table, and then push them into an array?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, discord.js

I'd like to get everything from a column called `userID` from a table called `userdata`, and then push all of that to an array to later be used for a `forEach()` loop, is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: Provide some code to check. We cannot imagine what all you need.

Comment: Rows don't have names... Do you mean column?

Comment: @Shawn yup! I'm really sorry for being dumb, a little bit new to this ~ Right, I'd like to get a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SQL query `SELECT userID FROM userdata`.
Where `SELECT` tries to select the paramater after it, which is the column `userID`. It then specifies where to get the data from, `FROM userdata` - the `userdata` table.

If you were using [better-sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-sqlite3), it would be as simple as:

```js
const rows = <db>.prepare('SELECT userID FROM userdata').all();
// rows: [ { userID: 'foo' }, { userID: 'foo' } ]
// With this array of objects, you are able to use a forEach loop

rows.forEach(object => {
  console.log(object.userID);
});
```